# How do I prevent a controller from creating unwanted routes?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, modules, yii

I have a custom module that is adding sections to the CP, like this:

```
// Register CP routes
Event::on(
    UrlManager::class,
    UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES,
    function(craft\events\RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
        $event->rules['<controller:(subscriptions|purchases)>/<action:>'] = [
            'route' => 'module/<controller>/<action>', 
            'defaults' => [
                'action' => 'index',
            ],
        ];
    }
);

// Add CP nav items
Event::on(
    Cp::class,
    Cp::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_NAV_ITEMS,
    function(craft\events\RegisterCpNavItemsEvent $event) {
        $event->navItems[] = [
            'url' => 'subscriptions',
            'label' => 'Subscriptions',
        ];
        $event->navItems[] = [
            'url' => 'purchases',
            'label' => 'Purchases',
        ];
    }
);
```

I have a `SubscriptionsController` and a `PurchasesController`, inside of which there is an `actionIndex()` method that computes some stuff and renders the appropriate template like this:

```
return $this->renderTemplate('module/cp/subscriptions/index', [
    'stuff' => $stuff,
]);
```

All this works fine, but I realized that the above registers some URLs that I do not want:

1) Controllers automatically register URLs in the format `admin/actions/<module>/<controller>/<action>` AND `actions/<module>/<controller/<action>`. I'm fine with the first one even though it causes duplicate URLs due to my custom `<controller:(subscriptions|purchases)>/<action:>` rule, but the second one is problematic because they're not even CP URLs, yet they invoke a controller that is only meant to be used in the CP. It's causing an error when trying to render the template, because the `module` template root is only registered for the CP with the code below:

```
// Set the base CP template directory
Event::on(
    View::class,
    View::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_TEMPLATE_ROOTS,
    function (craft\events\RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $event) {
        $event->roots['module'] = $this->getBasePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates';
    }
);
```

2) Craft automatically creates routes based on my template structure, meaning I can render the `module/subscriptions/index.twig` template directly from this URL: `admin/module/subscriptions`. This is also causing an error because the template requires variables that are passed to it in the controller action, but they're not set when rendering the template directly. I usually work around this issue on the front-end by setting the `general.php` config setting `privateTemplateTrigger` to an empty string `''`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the CP.

Any help with these two issues would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After too much time spent on this, I think I found a solution to both issues.

1) To prevent controller actions meant for the CP from being accessible on the front-end (via `actions/<module>/<controller>/<action>` URLs), simply add this line of code at the top of the action's method:

```
$this->requireCpRequest();
```

The non-CP action URLs will now return a `400` error.

2) Although it doesn't seem possible to change the private template trigger on the CP to prevent any template from being directly accessed with a URL, using an underscore at the beginning of any file or folder in the path works. But even better -- the template root itself can be private:

```
// Set the base CP template directory
Event::on(
    View::class,
    View::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_TEMPLATE_ROOTS,
    function(craft\events\RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $event) {
        $event->roots['_module'] = $this->getBasePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates';
    }
);
```

Notice the underscore in front of `_module`. This ensures that the module's templates will only render programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're "fighting the system" for no great gain, but anyway I think this is what you want:

```
    /**
     * @var bool|string[] Whether this controller’s actions can be accessed anonymously
     * If set to false, you are required to be logged in to execute any of the given controller's actions.
     * If set to true, anonymous access is allowed for all of the given controller's actions.
     * If the value is an array of action IDs, then you must be logged in for any actions except for the ones in
     * the array list.
     * If you have a controller that where the majority of actions allow anonymous access, but you only want require
     * login on a few, you can set this to true and call [[requireLogin()]] in the individual methods.
     */
    protected $allowAnonymous = false;
```